# Bind posted data to a model in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have seen other topics regarding this issue, didn't work out.

So in Laravel 5.4 Route Model Binding, we can bind a route to a model like:

define the route in web.php:

**web.php**:

```
Route::get('/users/{user}', UsersController@show);
```

**UsersController@show**:

```
public function show(User $user){
    // now we already have access to $user because of route model binding
    // so we don't need to use User::find($user), we just return it:
    return view(users.show, compact('user'));
}
```

The above code will work just fine, so in our controller we can return the $user without finding the user, we already have it.

but imagine this:

**web.php**:

```
Route::patch('/users/archive', UsersController@archive);
```

**EDITED:** **now the above line makes a *patch* route** and we don't have `{user}` in the route url, the user id is being posted via the form.

**UsersController@archive**:

```
public function archive(Request $request, User $user){
    // how can I access the $user here without using User::find($user);
    // I get to this action via a form which is posting `user` as a value like `5`
    dd($request->user); // this now echo `5`
    // I can do:
    // $user = User::find($request->user);
    // and it works, but is there a way to not repeat it every time in every action
}
```

What I have tried:
in RouteServiceProvider::boot() I have:

```
Route::model('user', 'App\User');
```

The above is what i have found in Google, but not working.

I would appreciate any kind of help.

---

**EDIT:**
It seems it's not called `Route Model Binding` anymore since we don't have the `{user}` in the `route` and that's because my code is not working, the `user` variable is being `post`ed to the controller and it's only accessible via `$request->user`.

this **is** route model binding:

```
Route::patch('users/{user}/archive', UsersController@archive);
```

this is **not**:

```
Route::patch('users/archive', UsersController@archive);
```

since we don't have `{user}` and it's being `post`ed via the form and could be accessed only via `$request->user`.
(please correct me if I am wrong about the definition of route model binding)

**SO:**

what I want to achieve in a nutshell: in every request being sent to my `UsersController`, if I am sending `user` variable as a `post` variable, it must be bounded to `User::findOrFail($request->user)` and then `$user` must be available in my controller actions.

I want to achieve this because in every action I am repeating myself doing `User::findOrFail($request->user)` and I don't want to do that, so I want to check in every request if I have a `variable name` like a `model name`, they should be bounded.

Comment: Did you try `public function archive(Request $request, User $user)`

Comment: @AliRasheed yup, not working

Comment: try `dd($request->all())`

Comment: @aldrin27 it shows all the posted data, I still have `"user" => "5"`

Comment: @aldrin27 but when I do: `dd($user->id)` it is `null`, so the bind didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to bind explicitly to the `User` class, so `Route::model('user', 'App\User');` should be removed; type-hinting should be enough instead.

```
public function archive(Request $request, User $user) { ... }
```

should be working, just make sure you are importing the right `User` class at the top of the file (`use App\User;`).

Then the model is in your `$user` variable (method argument), try `dd($user)`.

---

It's clear now that since the `{user}` variable is not in the URI, this is not a route model binding issue. You just want the User instance injected as a parameter based on the contents of the request.

```
$this->app->bind(User::class, function () {
    $user_id = request('user') ?: request()->route('user');
    return User::findOrFail($user_id);
});
```

You could add that to the `register` method in the `AppServiceProvider` (or any other registered provider) to have the model injected. I leave it to you to generalize this to other model classes.

Comment: well, yes, it should work, but it isn't! have you tried this in a `post` or `patch` method? since I read in laracasts that the variable name in the route you define must be your model name for this to work; and that's why I can make it working in a `get` route since I define the route like `Route::get('/users/{user}', UserController@show)`, but in this case since it's a  `patch` route `Route::patch('/users/{user}/archive', UsersController@archive)` and I don't have something like `{user}` in the route, that's why it isn't working! would you please check it in a `patch` route? thanks

Comment: route model binding works when you have the variable name in the route as the model name, that because I can get it to work in a get route: `Route::get('users/{user}/archive'@UserController@archive)`, this is working because I have `{user}` in the route and your code works in this situation, but in a patch route: `Route::patch('/users/archive', UsersController@archive)` I don't have `{user}` and that's because route model binding is not working! so in my case while the `user` is being posted to the controller and it's not in the route url, how can I use route model binding?

Comment: what I want to achieve in a nutshell: in every request being sent to my `UsersController`, if I am sending `user` variable as a `post` variable, it must be bounded to `User::findOrFail($request->user)` and it must be available in my controller actions.

Comment: @behz4d oh, so yeah, it's not route model binding then, if the parameter is not in the route. I'm updating my answer with 2 options to do what you want

Comment: what does `Route::model('user', 'App\User');` which I read somewhere else do?

Comment: another thing, so in some other routes which I route model bind the user, I mean i have `{user}` in route and the route model binding is working, is this gonna duplicate the query and run it twice??? since it's once being populated in laravel route model binding and also once again via appServiceProvider.php.  ?

Comment: @behz4d right, I updated the answer to handle route binding as well. The route parameter (the `'{user}'` part in the route definition) should match the name you give to the variable in the method signature (`User $user`). Instead, you could use any other name ( `Route::get('/{u}', ...)` ) and register that name with `Route::model('u', User::class)` and then in the method signature `User $anyOtherName` and it will be injected correctly

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need `(Request $request)` in your controller.

If you correctly imported User class, as alepeino said, you can access all user values from Model with this syntax `$user-><value>` for example:

```
public function archive(User $user) { 
  $userId = $user->id;
}
```

According to update.
If you use POST request, you can access it's data with such code `request()->get('<variable you send as parameter>')`
For example:

```
public function archive() { 
  $userId = request()->get('user');
  $userInfo = User::find($userId); 
  //Or as you said
 $user = User::findOrFail(request()->get('user'));
}
```

Comment: well, they probably need the $request which holds the patch data. (Unless they prefer to get that from a facade, or a "helper function")

Comment: route model binding works when you have the variable name in the route as the model name, that because I can get it to work in a `get` route: `Route::get('users/{user}/archive'@UserController@archive)`, this is working because I have `{user}` in the route and your code works in this situation, but in a patch route: `Route::patch('/users/archive', UsersController@archive)` I don't have `{user}` and that's because route model binding is not working! so in my case while the `user` is being posted to the controller and it's not in the route url, how can I use route model binding?

Answer (score -3):

Can you try this;

public function archive(Request $request, $u = User::find($user){

//now variable $u should point to the user with id from url

}

Comment: you cheated :))))) it's not route model binding!

Comment: nope, it seems it's an error to do this, ` (1/1) FatalErrorException

syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')'`